# An Abstract Object

Tags: java, oop

I'm looking for a definition of an abstract object. I cannot find it in my textbook and I've tried googling. Abstract classes and methods I understand. Anyone know what an abstract object is?

Comment: Where did you hear or read the term?

Comment: probably just abstraction in general. I.E we have abstract class , hence "" object.  Surely [not this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_object_theory)

Comment: @AniketThakur what part of *I cannot find it in my textbook and I've tried googling* didn't you get?

Comment: @AniketThakur: The OP has already tried searching - and seeing as "abstract object" isn't a term I've come across before, I'd be surprised to see any authoritative documentation...

Comment: Do you mean an *Anonymous Object*? Abstract Object sounds like a contradiction in terms to me.

Comment: I don't think we can instantiate abstract class. If anything, abstract object is just an abstract class reference to its subclass object?

Comment: @whiletrue Not true. You can never have an instance of an abstract class.

Comment: It could also be sloppy writing, where the author of what he read used "class" and "object" inappropriately.  Hard to tell without context.  Otherwise, "abstract object" does sound oxymoronic.

Comment: I'm studying for finals and this question was asked ''Define Abstract Object'' in a previous exam paper so I'm trying to be prepared. Looks like it may not exist so I just hope it's not asked this year!!

Comment: @JonSkeet I assumed by abstract object would OP meant polymorphic reference class of which is abstract. If "abstract object" is a new concept I would love to know more about it.

Comment: @AniketThakur please tell me in which part of that link is explained the concept of **abstract object**.

Comment: @Christopher: A Spaniel is an instance of Dog. Dog is most certainly abstract. There is no such thing as a (true/pure/only) Dog that isn't an instance of a concrete breed of Dog (possibly Mongrel...). So all Spaniels are instances of the abstract class Dog. Our whole taxonomy of the world relies on this trick of things being many things at various levels of abstraction and perspective. The 'idea' in OO is that it can be extended to programming. It has some benefits and some pitfalls. With care it can and does work.

Comment: @AniketThakur: class != object. The term "abstract class" is defined all over the place. The term "abstract object" isn't.

Comment: Please describe what you googled, what you found that didn't make sense.  Could you also include what you understand abstract classes to be and what you *think* you understand an abstract object to be along with the context that it was mentioned in. As it is, we can only guess as to what someone else meant when it was used - and it may have been used incorrectly. It may be you misunderstood the source and it *was* talking about abstract classes. It it may be something else completely. Either way, you ned to describe the problem you are having understanding something to get a good answer.

Comment: @SSI "Abstract object" is, as said above, a contradiction in terms: "abstract" can only be used in reference to a type and means that it cannot be instantiated directly, whereas "object" means an instance of a type. The only ways I can imagine the term "abstract object" coming up are (1) as a fragment of "abstract object type" (which means the same thing as "abstract class or interface"), or (2) as an unfortunate misnomer for #1. FWIW, I think your question is perfectly clear when read carefully enough, and if it wasn't on hold I'd post this as an answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as an abstract object, because an object would imply something is real, and an abstraction cannot be real. Because it is abstract.

In layman's terms, you cannot instantiate abstract classes, and an instantiated class is an object.

Comment: Why can't you have an object instance of which you know only the abstract type? Isn't that an abstract object?

Comment: I guess technically, you could have a derived class where all it did was inherit the abstract class, and instantiate that. However, that is still an object of it's derived form, not the abstract form.

Comment: I'm saying if a method's argument is an object defined only thru an interface isn't that method using without any knowledge of the concrete implementation? In that sense it is abstract no?

Comment: @nik: It's possible for the *type* of a *reference* (such as a method argument) to be abstract, but it's not possible for the *runtime-type* of an *object* to be abstract. If I write `AbstractSet<String> s = new HashSet<String>()`, it doesn't make sense to say that the new hash-set *object* is "abstract" just because the type of `s` doesn't give all the details.

Comment: +​1 despite the phrase "in layman's terms", which doesn't seem appropriate here. ("Instantiate" and "abstract class" are technical terms, not layman's terms. Do laymen even talk about these things?)

Answer (score 2):

There are abstract classes and methods, there is no such thing as an Abstract object. 
You cannot instantiate an Object from an Abstract class. 
You have to make another class extend it and override all the abstract methods it has.

This is why abstract classes are used, to put some constraints on a set of classes that have to extend it.

You should look into inheritance to see why abstract methods are used.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the notion of Abstract Object is not modeled in the language doesn't necessarily mean that it makes little sense. When we use objects and messages to represent elements of a given reality or fantasy some of them will have a more concrete meaning than others. For instance, if classes are first class objects in your system (cf. Smalltalk,) these objects could be deemed abstract when compared to their instances because they do not represent the thing but the concept associated to such a thing.

For example, the class WaterMolecule would be concrete as a class, its instances -representing H2O molecules- would also be concrete (as stated in the previous answers to this question) but the class WaterMolecule itself, *when considered as an object*, would fit the notion of an abstract object.

We could say that a class is an abstraction of level 1. An example of abstract object of level 2 would be the class of the class, namely the metaclass. If the metaclass is represented in the language as an object, this would qualify as an abstract object of level 2. Note that you can go a step further and consider the class of these objects, which would qualify as a concrete class (its instances are metaclasses) and, at the same time, as an abstract object (of level 3.)